# Get time from string in the same format

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I got string with datetime, and everytime this datetime in different format. Is it possible to get only time from string and save it's time format.

For example, Input:

```
"2010-10-23 01:02:45"
```

for this one as I understand there will be time in format HH:mm:ss.
I need resulted 01:02:45 (in the same format).

But for next input

```
"2010/1/23 1:05 AM"
```

time format is "h:mm tt"

How to parse it correctly?

Comment: Use [`DateTime.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx), then `ToString()` it in [whatever format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) you want

Comment: _"and everytime this datetime in different format"_ do you know at least all possible formats? Are they distinct, so isn't it possible that for example one time you get `2010-10-9` and the next time`2010-9-10`. Because then you had no chance

Comment: Try @maccettura 's advice with TryParse. If DateTime.TryParse has problems recognizing some of the occurring date/time formats, you may have to resort to regular expressions and do the parsing yourself for every format that may occur.

Comment: @Christoph: regex to parse `DateTime`? Nope. You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) with multiple format strings.

Comment: @TimSchmelter good point.

Answer (score 2):

For parsing a string to a `DateTime`, use the following (inline 'out' declaration is a C# 7 feature):

```
DateTime.TryParse("2010-10-23 01:02:45", out DateTime dateTime);
```

Then you can convert it to just the time (as you specified) using the following:

```
var time = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

All the available formats for parsing are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You can get them both in the same format however you want like this:

Live example:  http://rextester.com/HHKR44127

```
DateTime x;
DateTime y;
DateTime.TryParse("2010-10-23 01:02:45", out x);
DateTime.TryParse("2010/1/23 1:05 AM", out y);
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
Console.WriteLine(y.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```